# SQL Server analog of Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below Oracle query takes a comma-separated list of values, like `'3,4'`, and returns its individual tokens, `3` and `4`, in separate rows.

Can somebody please show how to do the same in SQL Server.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('3,4','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it would be helpfull,if you can show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189734/replace-regexp-substr-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: @TheGameiswar - it is all there in the post:  the input is a string, `'3,4'`. The desired output is, as stated in the question, to separate the values `3` and `4`. And the OP shows one of the correct and efficient ways to do that in Oracle. He wants to know how to do it in SQL Server.

Comment: @mathguy:i am not totally sure about `REGEXP_SUBSTR('3,4','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)`,so asked for some enhancements

Comment: @TheGameiswar - OK, I edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: please look at this link  if you are using versions below sql 2016,https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: if you are using sql2016,you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt684588.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The query would use a recursive CTE.  I think this is the logic:

```
with c as (
      select '3,4' as rest, NULL as val
      union all
      select stuff(rest, charindex(',', rest + ',') + 1),
             left(rest, charindex(',', rest + ',') - 1)
      from c
     )
select col
from c;
```

I should note that Oracle 12c supports recursive CTEs, which I (at least) find more intuitive than `connect by`.