# SQL- Extracting Text between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

This is what my data looks like.  (I'm trying to exact email address so I can send emails for TO and CC person.)

```
    EmailTO:[url=mailto:Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com[/url]             
    EmailCC:[url=mailto:Test_Email_2@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_2@Yahoo.com[/url]           

    Hello, This is the rest of the email message....
```

When I run this 1st SQL I get my desired results.

```
    Select
    Body,
    SUBSTRING(Body, CHARINDEX('EmailTO', Body) + 20,CHARINDEX(']',Body)-CHARINDEX('EmailTO',Body)-20) ToEmail
```

This returns

```
    ToEmaiL = Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com
```

But when I try to do a second SUBSTRING like this

```
    Select
    Body,
    SUBSTRING(Body, CHARINDEX('EmailTO', Body) + 20,CHARINDEX(']',Body)-CHARINDEX('EmailTO',Body)-20) ToEmail,
    SUBSTRING(Body, CHARINDEX('EmailCC', Body) + 20,CHARINDEX(']',Body)-CHARINDEX('EmailCC',Body)-20) CCEmail --(Simply replacing the EmailTo from the previous line to EmailCC)
    From hdIssues
```

I get this error

```
    "Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."
```

Any help is appreciated.

**P.S. in my dataset the email addresses can have multiple recipients separated by a semicolon like this:**

```
[url=mailto:Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com[/url]; [url=mailto:Test_Email_5@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_5@Yahoo.com[/url]; [url=mailto:Test_Email_8@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_8@Yahoo.com[/url]
```

Comment: SQL is really the wrong tool for the job, especially with that ps.

Comment: What database?  mySQL?  Oracle?  Add the appropriate tag to your question; and as HoneyBadger pointed out, SQL is probably not the best choice; I would think a few Unix commands would make quick work  of this.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If open to a TVF

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.Body,'[url=mailto:',']') B
```

Returns

```
ID  RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1   1       23      Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com
1   2       89      Test_Email_5@Yahoo.com
1   3       155     Test_Email_8@Yahoo.com
1   4       229     Test_Email_2@Yahoo.com
```

**The TVF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - For Body**

The two delimeters are `'[/url]'` and `'|||'` .  We force then ending delimiter by adding a unique string.  In this case I picked `|||`

If you don't want the multipe records.  Remove `CROSS APPLY B`

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
      ,Body = ltrim(rtrim(C.RetVal))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.Body,'[url=mailto:',']') B
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](A.Body+'|||','[/url]','|||') C  --- Notice A.Body+'|||'.... this is to force an ending delimiter
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: John,  This is great and I definitely can use this on a different project I'm working on.  Unfortunately for this particular project it doesn't quite work. 

After re-reading my initial question, I forgot to mention that these email address are not static, why will Change all the time.  So by hard coding the email addresses in the code above will only give results when those email addresses are use.

Comment: @StephenMorrell What is hard coded?  The (at)YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.

Comment: The body column is actually the the body of the email message.  In these messages, the EmailTO and EMAILCC will always change, the Declare statement above it shows as: 

(1, '
EmailTO:[url=mailto:Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com[/url]; [url=mailto:Test_Email_5@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_5@Yahoo.com[/url]; [url=mailto:Test_Email_8@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_8@Yahoo.com[/url]
EmailCC:[url=mailto:Test_Email_2@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_2@Yahoo.com[/url]           

    Hello, This is the rest of the email message....
')

how do I get this to use the Column called "Body" instead?

Comment: PERFECT!!!!! thank you so much!!!!!  how do I mark this as answered and give you credit?

Comment: @StephenMorrell Always happy to help  :)

Comment: @StephenMorrell So I lost the accepted status?  OK.

Comment: please check now.

Comment: @StephenMorrell I see it now :)   The other selected anwer would only return 1 To and 1 CC.  Got me curious.  My world makes sense now.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use regexp_substr

```
with t1(col) as(
   select 'EmailTO:[url=mailto:Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com] Test_Email_1@Yahoo.com[/url]' from dual
)

select regexp_substr(col, '[[:alnum:]._%-]+@[[:alnum:]._%-]+\.com') as res
  from t1;
```

This will pull both email addresses out, which I left because you said in your P.S. that multiple email addresses may exist. You could modify the regular expression to only pull out a single copy of each email.

Comment: I get this Error:

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6 'regexp_substr' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought this had an Oracle tag on it. regexp_substr is an Oracle function. Try this instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189734/replace-regexp-substr-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem with your query, you need to start the search for the EmailCC after the first ']' character.  Otherwise, you pick up the first occurance of the ']' character which is BEFORE 'EmailCC' and thus the error.  You can do this by add a "start_location" for the CHARINDEX().

So change your query to the following:

```
    Select
    Body,
    SUBSTRING(Body, CHARINDEX('EmailTO', Body) + 20,CHARINDEX(']',Body)-CHARINDEX('EmailTO',Body)-20) ToEmail,
    SUBSTRING(Body, CHARINDEX('EmailCC', Body) + 20,CHARINDEX(']',Body, CHARINDEX('EmailCC', Body))-CHARINDEX('EmailCC',Body)-20) CCEmail
    From hdIssues
```

View the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql